# JSON.parse on array of JSON strings not doing as expected

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to javascript so learning how some of this stuff works.

I have a string that looks like: `["{\"name\":\"name\"}","{\"name\":\"Rick\"}"]`

If I JSON.parse() that shouldn't it return an array of objects that have a property of name?

What I get is 2 elements in an array but they are just the JSON strings. They are not objects with property name. What am I missing?

[EDIT]
I was calling stringify() on the object and then passing it to the array instead of just passing the object as is to the array. Then I stringify() the array. I was stringifying a stringify which caused it to put the escape characters :)

Comment: Tip, alternate ' and " characters.  You don't have to escape ' or " if it is inside a string of `""` or `''` respectively. I.e. `'[{"name":"name"},{"name":"Rick"}]'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I JSON.parse() that shouldn't it return an array of objects that have a property of name?

No, it looks like the JSON defines an array with two strings in it.

This is the JSON for an array with two strings in it:

```
[
    "{\"name\":\"name\"}",
    "{\"name\":\"Rick\"}"
]
```

In JavaScript string literal form, that's `'["{\"name\":\"name\"}","{\"name\":\"Rick\"}"]'`.

This is the JSON for an array with two objects in it:

```
[
    {
        "name": "name"
    },
    {
        "name": "Rick"
    }
]
```

In JavaScript string literal form, that would be `'[{"name":"name"},{"name":"Rick"}]'`.

Comment: That's strange because I'm not manually adding those escape characters. When I stringify() an array they seem to be getting added automatically. Testing with IE 10 on Win 8.

Comment: tmp.push(JSON.stringify(data)); where the data is an object. tmp looks normal. It holds 1 element of the JSON string and visually in VS it looks normal. After calling localStorage.setItem(tbl.name, JSON.stringify(tmp)); and looking in localStorage it now has the escape chars in it.

Comment: @user441521: I expect it's to do with however you're looking at the string. For instance, in Chrome's console, `JSON.stringify([{"foo":"bar"}])` outputs `"[{"foo":"bar"}]"` (note how it's putting quotes around the string, but not escaping quotes within the string, which would be wrong if you copy-and-pasted it). `JSON.stringify` works correctly on IE9 ([example](http://jsbin.com/owexuf/1)), I don't see any reason to believe it doesn't work correctly on IE10. Hope this helps,

Comment: I found the problem. I stringify() the object when I add it to the array and then I stringify() the array. I just changed it to push the object as is to the array and keep the stringify() on the array and it works! Thanks!

Comment: @user441521: Ah, that makes sense. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 2):

I guess its sholuld come as:

```
"[{\"name\":\"name\"},{\"name\":\"Rick\"}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you lose the (escaped) quotes around the root elements you might get what you want.

E.g. something like

```
"[{"name":"name"},{"name":"Rick"}]"
```